# $L^2$-norm of sum smaller than $L^2$-norm of either summand

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $\Vert f \Vert_2 = \Vert g \Vert_2$. If $\Vert f + g \Vert_2 \leqslant \Vert f \Vert_2$, does it necessarily follow that for almost all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, either $g(x)=-f(x)$ or $g(x)=f(x)$?

This looks like a question where the answer should be known, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere. If $f$ and $g$ are such functions, the assumptions imply that they satisfy a strong version of the triangle inequality, namely

\begin{align}
\Vert f + g \Vert_2 \leqslant \tfrac{1}{2} (\Vert f \Vert_2 + \Vert g \Vert_2).
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is false. Consider

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \sqrt{x} & \text{for }(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1], \\ 0 & \text{for } (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus [0,1] \times [0,1],\end{cases}$$

and

$$g(x,y)=\begin{cases} -\sqrt{y} & \text{for }(x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1], \\ 0 & \text{for } (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus [0,1] \times [0,1].\end{cases}$$

Notice that

$$||f||^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}xdxdy=\frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad ||g||^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}ydxdy=\frac{1}{2},$$

that is, $||f||=||g||=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ Also,

$$||f+g||^{2}=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^{2}dxdy=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1}(x+y-2\sqrt{xy})dxdy=\frac{1}{9},$$

so that $$||f+g||=\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=||f||.$$

Therefore, these functions satisfies all the conditions but $f \neq g$.